# Problem with importing Python file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, file, import, module

I'm learning how to code starting with Python, and I'm facing a problem trying to import a file as a module. With this code :

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()+"\launch")
import launch as l
```

I'm getting the issue "Import "launch" could not be resolved", and if I execute the script, the error "ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'launch'".
I'm struggling with this for a few hours now, and I'm quite desperate, so thanks in advance for your answers !

Of course, with the command :

```
os.popen(os.getcwd()+"\launch")
```

I can open my file, so it's not a problem of wrong path.

Comment: You never import anything called `lancer`... Where are you getting that error? Does the `launch` module import something called `lancer`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, I'm French, it's a problem with my translation

Comment: The error is still her though